Can't add a package source to Nuget package manager
When I try adding it, the add button is disabled. Does anyone know how to resolve this? I didn't have any problems with the Nuget package manager a couple of days ago.

Don't mind this text, I just needed to get the required number of characters to submit the question.

The screenshot shows adding a "Package Source Mapping", not a "Package Source". Adding sources is in the menu option above.

Nevermind then. I just panicked since a nuget package wasn't downloading but I tried downloading another one, turns out there's a problem with that specific package, and I didn't recognise this feature since it wasn't in VS 2019. Thanks for the comment.

In Visual Studio, when managing NuGet packages, the terms "package source" and "package source mapping" refer to distinct aspects of how NuGet packages are handled within projects:

Package Source:

A package source in Visual Studio refers to the locations where NuGet packages can be fetched. These sources can be either online repositories (such as the official NuGet Gallery, a custom URL, or a private feed) or local directories on your machine. In the Visual Studio settings, you can manage these sources, adding new ones or removing existing ones, to control where your projects search for and download packages. This setting allows developers to specify different repositories for retrieving the packages they need.


Package Source Mapping:

Introduced in NuGet 6.0 and Visual Studio 2022, package source mapping adds a layer of control over which packages are retrieved from which sources. This feature lets you map specific package patterns (like package IDs or prefixes) to particular sources. For example, you can configure your settings so that all packages starting with "Contoso." are fetched from a specific private feed while other packages are retrieved from the public NuGet gallery. This is especially useful in enterprise environments to ensure that projects use the correct internal packages instead of similarly named packages available in public repositories. It enhances security by preventing unintentional usage of packages from untrusted sources and helps to manage dependencies more explicitly.



